# Location of a variable giving me an unexpected result on the infamous FizzBuzz

Tags: javascript

While working on my **FizzBuzz** I was getting an unexpected result even when the logic appear to be fine.

Fist I had the variable `output` outside the `for` loop and got an unexpected result.

```js
var output = '';
for (var count = 1; count <= 100; count++) {
  if ( count % 3 == 0)
    output += 'Fizz';
  if ( count % 5 == 0)
    output += 'Buzz';
  console.log( output || count );
}
```

After a while I just moved the `output` variable inside the `for` loop and got the expected result:

```js
for (var count = 1; count <= 100; count++) {
  var output = ''; // Variable moved inside the for loop
  if ( count % 3 == 0)
    output += 'Fizz';
  if ( count % 5 == 0)
    output += 'Buzz';
  console.log( output || count );
}
```

but still I'm not understanding the nature of the issue. Why it doesn't work with the `output` variable outside of the for loop but it does work with the variable inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having `var output = ''` inside the loop, each time the loops restarts, the `output` variable will reset to `''`.

```
for (var count = 1; count <= 3; count++)    
{
    var output = ''
    output += count;
    console.log(output);
}

>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
```

If you have the `var output` outside the loop, the variable will remember it's content, and by using `output += count` the `count` variable will be appended to the `output`

```
var output = ''
for (var count = 1; count <= 3; count++)    
{
    output += count;
    console.log(output);
}

>>> 1
>>> 12
>>> 123
```